# Spring MVC: Post 2 inputs and transform to Date type

Tags: java, spring

**Controller**

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
        @InitBinder
        public void binder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest webRequest) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(WorkRequest.SimpleDate.class, new DatePropertyEditor());
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String post(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") UserRequest request, final BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    ...
    }
```

**Complex Object Type**

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class UserRequest {
        @Valid
        @NotNull(message = "Enter work experience")
        @Size(min = 1, message = "Enter work experience")
        private List<WorkRequest> works;
    }


    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class WorkRequest {
        @Valid
        @XmlTransient
        private SimpleDate sDate;
        @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
        public Date startDate;  
    ...
    }
```

**JSP**

```
<form:form action="${url}" method="POST" commandName="form">
 <form:select path="works[0].sDate.month" items="${monthsMap}"></form:select>
 <form:select path="works[0].sDate.year" items="${yearMap}"></form:select>
</form:form>
```

**PROBLEM/ SOLUTION NEEDED**
I would like to bind sDate.month + sDate.year to startDate @java.util.Date in WorkRequest.java

However, initBinder doesn't seem to support setting works[0].sDate.year. In the post, initBinder responds to works[0].sDate. Can someone please suggest of converting Month + Year to Date while making POST?